# Different format in terminal vs in a .txt document

Tags: shell-script, date, printf

I have a script that tracks time.

When I print my output in my console I get this:

```
0 Days, 00:00:33
```

When I save it to a txt file I get this:

```
^[[2K
  0 Days, 00:00:33
```

Code:

```
now=$(date +%s)
diff=$(($now - $begin))
mins=$(($diff / 60))
secs=$(($diff % 60))
hours=$(($diff / 3600))
days=$(($diff / 86400))

printf "\33[2K\r%3d Days, %02d:%02d:%02d" $days $hours $mins $secs
printf "\33[2K\r%3d Days, %02d:%02d:%02d" $days $hours $mins $secs >> test.txt
```

Where is the `^[[2K`coming from? I'm guessing it has something to do with the format in printf.

I read a bit about printf here: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf. But I didn't get any wiser....

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have escape control sequences in your `printf` command i.e. `printf "\33[2K.....`, (`\e[2K` clears a line), that is necessarily a control command for the terminal, that can only be understood and acted upon by a terminal device.

When you are running the script interactively inside the terminal, the terminal is interpreting the sequence properly. While saving the command's output in a file, the sequence is being treated literally as there is nothing to interpret the sequence then.

Now if you do:

```
cat test.txt
```

you'll see that the terminal is interpreting the sequence correctly again before the output being printed.

Answer (score 5):

The succession of lines

```
printf "\33[2K\r%3d Days, %02d:%02d:%02d" $days $hours $mins $secs
printf "\33[2K\r%3d Days, %02d:%02d:%02d" $days $hours $mins $secs >> test.txt
```

is defined to print time information on *the same line* of a terminal.  That **`\33[2K`** clears the entire (current) line, and the **`\r`** moves the cursor to the beginning of the line.  The effect is to make the time information which changes, just appear to change *that* part of the line.

I noticed that there is no newline (**`\n`**) in the format.  The question shows line-breaks (perhaps those were added for clarity).

Answer (score 4):

You wrote it yourself, as

```
\33[2K
```

Depending on your terminal, it will understand that as an instruction to perform some action.  Since you mentioned "console", you can consult the `console_codes(4)` man page, where this is listed:

> ### ECMA-48 CSI sequences
>
> `CSI`  (or  `ESC [`) is followed by a sequence of parameters, at most *NPAR* (16), that are decimal numbers separated by semicolons.  An empty or absent parameter is taken to be 0.  The sequence of parameters may be preceded by a single question mark.
>
> ...
>
> #### `K`:   EL  -     Erase line
>
> default: from cursor to end of line.
> **`ESC [ 1 K`**: erase from start of line to cursor.
> **`ESC [ 2 K`**: erase whole line.

(It helps to recall that `\033` is the same as `ESC`).

So your escape sequence is the "erase whole line" command to this terminal.

The portable (and clearer) way to write this would be

```
clear_line=`tput cr; tput el`
printf "${clear_line}%3d Days, %02d:%02d:%02d" $days $hours $mins $secs
```

Using `tput` means that when writing to a terminal that doesn't support the `el` action, or that supports it with a different escape sequence, you'll get the appropriate output rather than unintelligible garbage.

---

P.S. All that arithmetic is probably unnecessary, assuming GNU `date`.  If you never exceed 7 days, you can get it down to

```
date -u -d "-$begin seconds +3days" '+${clear_line}%w days, %T'
```

Otherwise, you still need to compute `$days`, but you can format the seconds with `%T`:

```
now=$(date +%s)
diff=$(($now - $begin))
days=$(($diff / 86400))
date -u -d "00:00 $diff seconds" '+${clear_line}$days days, %T'
```